# Horrific libPNG performance on iOS

Tags: android, c++, ios, png, libpng

I'm currently using the open-source libPNG library to read & decompress bitmaps.  It works great on Android, OS X, and Win32 but for some reason performs *30X* slower on iOS devices.  The same libPNG source code tree (unmodified) is used on all platforms.

Several things I found in the Cocos2D forums lead me to believe it's an issue with the zlib implementation on iOS, but I've tried using both stb_image and LodePng to avoid zlib and those libraries actually performed EVEN WORSE than libPNG!

Is there some special way of building libPNG "properly" for iOS?  If not then what is libPNG doing that's *SO* much slower on iOS?  Why would stb_image also be slow/slower?  Is there a known way to work around or correct this problem?

Thanks,
AF

Comment: You can use CoreGraphics on iOS and OS X to load PNG images.  The basic procedure is to load the PNG with `CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider`, then create a bitmap context (`CGBitmapContextCreate`) and draw the PNG into the bitmap context.  This way you can avoid LibPNG altogether.

Comment: Could you be measuring mainly the slower file system bandwidth on iOS devices? There is also an iOS device bandwidth limit in getting large bitmaps into the GPU for display, varies by OS version and device model.

Comment: It's not gpu-related, just decompressing the .png from one memory buffer to another using.  The specific function that eats all the time is "png_read_image()".

Comment: It would be worth knowing the answer even if a workaround is found. Who knows what else it affects?

Comment: FWIW I wound up using "CGBitmapContextCreate()" to decompress an in-memory .png file on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to rebuild zlib and this may solve your problem.
If not, try looking for some popular open source iOS applications that support PNG, which may have worked around this issue. You can even post on their forums.